# How to add Jsoup to my Android Studio project?

Tags: java, android, jsoup, android-studio-2.2

I am trying to use jsoup in my android studio project but i keep getting this error: Error:(10, 16) Gradle: error: package org.jsoup does not exist.

Could you guys tell me the steps on how to add jsoup library to my project? Thanks in advance.

Edit: For learning purpuse i am running the java code alone without main activity!

code:

```
package com.jsoupTest.jsoupTest;


import java.io.IOException;




import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JsoupGetRequest {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



        String dc=Jsoup.connect("http://somelink.com").timeout(6000).get();
        System.out.println(dc);
    }

}
```

Comment: a `main`-method in an android project? This looks suspicious!
Anyway, try adding this to your build.gradle `compile group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.9.1'` as dependency  and remove `compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:+';` from your class.
`

Comment: Thanks for reply . I am new to android studio could you tell me how to reach build.gradle dependency section ?

Answer (score 12):

Gradle (build.gradle) in your app folder. put under dependencies section. clean and rebuild project

```
// jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
```

Comment: That fixed the first error. I am running the java code without main activity and now i get this error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
 at com.javagetrequest.javagetrequest.JsoupGetRequest.main(JsoupGetRequest.java:37)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Answer (score 2):

You should add your dependencies in your build.gradle file.
Please check the screenshot attached.

[image: build.gradle file location on Android Studio]

Comment: I am in that location what should i do there ?

Comment: just add compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3' under dependencies section